# check if ArrayList<String> have the item already

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

I have an ArrayList that her content come from the user...
and i want the user to be unable to put the same content twice.
How can i do it ?

```
addArray.add(firstHouer + " " + firstdMinute + " - " + seccoundHouer + " " + seccoundMinute);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not use HashMap for this. Then you can check whether a particular key already exists https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: "and i want the user to be unable to put the same content twice" then you may not want List but Set. If you also want to preserve order you can use LinkedHashSet as implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can  check it by `contains` method:

```
if (!addArray.contains(...)) {
    addArray.add();
}
```

or just use a `HashSet<String>`, which will handle repeated elements automatically.  The same element is guaranteed appear once at most.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check duplicate on your MyObject, you can use write a method getKey(): String in your MyObject, and use HashSet to check dup key.

An example in your case:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<MyObject> items = new ArrayList<>();
    HashSet<String> checkDup = new HashSet<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        addObject(new MyObject(1, 30));
        addObject(new MyObject(2, 30));
        addObject(new MyObject(1, 30)); // dup content will be skip
        addObject(new MyObject(5, 0));


        for (MyObject item : items) {
            Log.d("hiepxuan2008", item.hour + " - " + item.minute);
        }
    }

    void addObject(MyObject obj) {
        if (!checkDup.contains(obj.getKey())) {
            checkDup.add(obj.getKey());
            items.add(obj);
        }
    }

    // Your custom Object
    class MyObject {
        public int hour;
        public int minute;
        public MyObject(int hour, int minute) {
            this.hour = hour;
            this.minute = minute;
        }

        public String getKey() {
            return hour + "-" + minute;
        }
    }
}
```

And the results:

1 - 30

2 - 30

5 - 0

Hope it will help in your issue. Thank you!